# Using Unity namespace issue, using (UnityEngine)

Tags: file, unity-game-engine, namespaces, using

I have a question about this one, I have never encountered this problem before, and I have no idea how to solve it. As you can see in the picture if I leave the Addressable_Spawn_selection script in the Asset file, it can use Unity.Engine.AddressableAssets without any problem. The issue is somehow my script in another folder cant access this script, it can only be accessed when I put both scripts in the same folder. Check the third picture. This allows my other script to access this script. But somehow the script then can no longer access Unity.Engine.AddressableAssets or Tmpro(TextmeshPro)(Check the fourth picture).
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That other folder does it (or some of the parent folders) have its own [Assembly Definition](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html) (`.asmdef` file)? If so you will need to explicitly reference the addressables assembly as a dependency!

Answer (score 0):

I found where is the issue, which is the API that I've downloaded has its own definition that is not assembly c, and has its own "DLL". Go to that definition and add the reference inside that script: for example, add the file of the plugin like TmPro(TextmeshPro)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).